# Making a js thermometer

Tags: javascript

I'm making this thermometer with JS where you can write in a form the grades of the temperature and after clicking the button a function will make an image appear.  I want to change the image after I change the data in the form and click the button again but my code does not seem to work

I'm trying to do it with simple JS because I want to understand the process step by step (I'm not making a thermometer out of need but as an exercise)

```
let imgaparecio = true;
console.log(imgaparecio);

function getValue() {
    var kelv = document.getElementById("kelvin");
    var cel = document.getElementById("celsius");
    var fah = document.getElementById("fahrenheit");
    var ik;
    var ic;
    var ifh;
    if (imgaparecio) {
        ik = document.createElement("IMG");
        ik.style.width = "40%";
        ik.style["max-height"] = "380px";
        ik.style["min-height"] = "380px";
        ik.style["object-position"] = "center";
        kelv.appendChild(ik);

        console.log("first time activated");
        return [ik, ic, ifh, imgaparecio = false];
    } else {
        console.log("this is activated already");
    }

    var cambio = document.getElementById("wrote").value;
    var kelvin = Math.floor(cambio);
    var celsius = kelvin - 273;
    var fahrenheit = Math.floor(celsius * (9 / 5) + 32);

    if (kelvin <= 0 && kelvin < 200) {
        ik.setAttribute("src", "./img/zero.png");
    } else if (kelvin >= 200 && kelvin < 400) {
        ik.setAttribute("src", "./img/twofive.png");
    } else if (kelvin >= 400 && kelvin < 600) {
        ik.setAttribute("src", "./img/fifty.png");
    } else if (kelvin >= 600 && kelvin < 800) {
        ik.setAttribute("src", "./img/sevenfive.png");
    } else {
        ik.setAttribute("src", "./img/fullter.png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ik` you are using the hold the image is declared inside `getValue()`, making it a local variable. When you run `getValue()` for the second time, you skip the block that creates a new image. This leaves `ik` undefined and so the code that sets its source will fail.

If you move your line `var ik;` outside of `getValue()` and into the global scope next to the `let imgaparecio = true;` declaration, it should work.